# what does d3.event.dx return?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am learning d3 drag, and I am stuck here with this line  `d3.event.dx`. When I output this value in console, it returns me some int value as I drag the point, which I don't know what pattern this returned value follows. Could anyone explain?

```
vis.selectAll("circle.control")
    .data(function(d) { return points.slice(0, d) }) // array contains 2 3 ... 5 points respectively 
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", "control")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", x)
    .attr("cy", y)
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart", function(d) {
        this.__origin__ = [d.x, d.y];
        //alert(this.__origin__);
      })
      .on("drag", function(d) {
        d.x = Math.min(w, Math.max(0, this.__origin__[0] += d3.event.dx));
        //alert(this.__origin__[0]);
        //alert(d3.event.dx);
        console.log(d3.event.dx);
       // console.log (d.x);

        d.y = Math.min(h, Math.max(0, this.__origin__[1] += d3.event.dy));

        //alert(this.__origin__[1]);
        bezier = {};
        update();
        vis.selectAll("circle.control")
          .attr("cx", x)
          .attr("cy", y);
      })
      .on("dragend", function() {
        delete this.__origin__;
      }));
```

Answer (score 2):

d3.event.dx returns the x delta that the mouse has moved w.r.t to the x-coordinate from where the drag event started.

https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#user-content-drag-events

Comment: The link should be updated. https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#user-content-drag-events

Answer (score 1):

The `dx` member of the event object will be some coordinate, but probably not something that is meaningful for you. `d3.event` is the [DOM event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event), so the information contained may not reflect what you're doing in your visualisation.

You can use other methods provided by d3 to get more meaningful information, e.g. `d3.mouse()` to get the coordinates relative to a container. More information in the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-d3_event).